# Why is data in my database entered with 2 blank rows between two entries?

Tags: php, mysql

A snippet of a table in my database:
[image]

And my PHP is this:

```
 <?php
     $item="";
        try{
        if ( ! empty($_POST['item_name'])){
        $item=$_POST['item_name'];
        }        
        $servername = "localhost";
        $conusername = "root";
        $conpassword = "";
        $dbname = "annapoorna";
        $dsn='mysql:dbname='.$dbname.';host='.$servername;
        $conn = new PDO($dsn, $conusername, $conpassword);
        $sql='INSERT INTO item(item_name) values (:item_name)';
        $sth=$conn->prepare($sql); 
        $sth->execute(array(':item_name'=>$item ));
        }

catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
     }
   ?>
```

Why is the gap there between two entries? It is happening in every table that I'm creating.

Comment: close `if ( ! empty($_POST['item_name'])){` at the end of your code to avoide empty entry

Comment: In the try block itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your add code in if conditions

```
  if (!empty($_POST['item_name'])){
        $item=$_POST['item_name'];
        $servername = "localhost";
        $conusername = "root";
        $conpassword = "";
        $dbname = "annapoorna";
        $dsn='mysql:dbname='.$dbname.';host='.$servername;
        $conn = new PDO($dsn, $conusername, $conpassword);
        $sql='INSERT INTO item(item_name) values (:item_name)';
        $sth=$conn->prepare($sql); 
        $sth->execute(array(':item_name'=>$item ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the `POST` parameter to `$item` only if it is set.

```
if ( ! empty($_POST['item_name'])){
    $item=$_POST['item_name'];
}
```

When it isn't set, `$item` is undefined, which evaluates to an empty string.

```
$sth->execute(array(':item_name'=>$item ));
```

So you'll want to change the code so that you don't insert when `$item` is not set.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is telling the application if not empty `$_POST['item_name']` give `$item` its value and execute the code below. If `$_POST['item_name']` IS empty the code below still executes with an emtpy variable and thus empty records. change your code so that it only executes when the `$_POST['item_name']` is filled:

```
<?php
     $item="";
        try{
        if ( ! empty($_POST['item_name'])){
        $item=$_POST['item_name'];

        $servername = "localhost";
        $conusername = "root";
        $conpassword = "";
        $dbname = "annapoorna";
        $dsn='mysql:dbname='.$dbname.';host='.$servername;
        $conn = new PDO($dsn, $conusername, $conpassword);
        $sql='INSERT INTO item(item_name) values (:item_name)';
        $sth=$conn->prepare($sql); 
        $sth->execute(array(':item_name'=>$item ));
         }
        }

catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
     }
   ?>
```

It is as simple as changing the end of you `if` statement.